# Как преобразовать датафрейм в новый и добавить новые столбцы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Есть фрейм данных:

```
                            0        2        3  5
0     2021-03-23 07:06:27.758  1.19236  1.19237  6
1     2021-03-23 07:06:31.898  1.19237  1.19238  6
2     2021-03-23 07:06:33.196  1.19237  1.19240  4
3     2021-03-23 07:06:33.919  1.19237  1.19238 -4
4     2021-03-23 07:06:36.596  1.19237  1.19239  4
...                       ...      ...      ... ..
87309 2021-03-24 09:01:07.234  1.18443  1.18462  4
87310 2021-03-24 09:01:07.640  1.18443  1.18461 -4
87311 2021-03-24 09:01:07.742  1.18443  1.18460 -4
87312 2021-03-24 09:01:08.201  1.18443  1.18461  4
87313 2021-03-24 09:01:14.891  1.18444  1.18461  2
```

Который толком особо ничего не передает, однако появилась идея его преобразовать в новый с шагом в 1м. Идея такая: в нов. `df2` имеются колонки:

```
  time        znachen_one   znachen_end  srings  max_2   min_2 max_3 min_3   6  4  2  0 -2  -4  -6
```

- где в колонке `time` берется первая дата
- в колонке `znachen_one` первое значение
- в колонке `znachen_end` последнее значение
- в колонке `srings` кол-во строк между `znachen_one` и `znachen_end`, если брать шаг в 1м , то их разное кол-во
- в колонках 6 4 2 0 -2 -4 -6  кол-во из колонки 5 старого `df`, т.е. из примера выше "6"-2раза, "4"-4раза, "-4" - 4 раза, "2"-1 раз, если некоторых параметров нет, то просто ставится 0 (нуль)
- в колонках `max` и `min` соответственно максимальное и минимальное значение из колонок 2 и 3

Kаким методом выставить шаг и как это вообще будет выглядеть?
Как заполнить остальные колонки ?

Comment: __Необходимо конкретизировать.__ 
Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вам удочка, рыбу, надеюсь, сами научитесь ловить.
;)

Воспользуйтесь группировкой и [агрегатными функциями](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html).

Пример:

```
funcs = {
    "znachen_one": ("2", "first"), 
    "znachen_end": ("2", "last"), 
    "srings": ("0", "size"),
    # ...
}
res = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="0", freq="1T")).agg(**funcs)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, теперь хоть знаю что искать и в чем разбираться)